# SELECT COUNT query matching 100 million rows from a 1 billion row table takes 30 seconds even with an index

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, query-optimization

I’m trying to understand indexes in MySQL and how they work and how much they improve speed. I made a table with 1 billion rows, which has a column called ‘index_this’ containing 10 possible string values, roughly evenly distributed (so each value is found in roughly 100 million rows). Here is the query I’m running.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydatabase.mytable WHERE mytable.index_this = ‘A1ndxstring’;
```

Running this query takes 30 seconds, with a BTREE index on the ‘index_this’ column. I checked whether the query optimizer is using the index.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mydatabase.mytable WHERE mytable.index_this = ‘A1ndxstring’;
```

returns

```
id              1
select_type     SIMPLE
table           mytable
type            ref
possible_keys   index_this
key             index_this
key_len         43
ref             const
rows            188130384
Extra           Using where; Using index
```

Here is how I created my index.

```
CREATE INDEX myindex ON mydatabase.mytable (index_this);
```

I didn’t specify a prefix length, but previously I did try it with a prefix length of 2, and that just made the query take almost 100 times as long. Is 30 seconds reasonable for this table size and this query, even with an index? I’m looking for any advice on how I can improve speed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the right index. But there are very few values, so you still need to count about 100 million rows. How about throwing some hardware at it?

Comment: How accurate do you need the number? Is the `EXPLAIN` output sufficient? Do you get a better estimate with [persistent stats](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html)?

Comment: Create a summary table to keep a running total with a trigger for a stored procedure to update on each insert, then run the query against the summary table.

Comment: 30secs is pretty good for that volume.

Comment: Having a table with 1billion entries results mostly from a bad database design

Comment: @GMB Just so I’m sure I understand correctly, are you saying that if I had, say, 1000 possible string values instead of 10, then the query would take a shorter time because I’d only need to count 1 million rows instead of 100 million? For hardware, I’m running Ubuntu 18 LTS with 16 GB RAM and a Core i7-7700. I could upgrade to 32 GB RAM, but is 30 seconds reasonable for my current hardware?

Comment: @danblack Currently I’m running benchmarks to get a sense of how much indexing and optimizations improve performance, so I want the number to be completely accurate and the `EXPLAIN` output isn’t sufficient. I already have `innodb_stats_persistent` = ON since it’s on by default. I also ran `ANALYZE TABLE` just to be sure, and afterward the query still took 30 seconds.

Comment: @miknik My objective right now isn’t to actually get the information about how many rows contain a certain string value. It’s to find out how long getting that information would take, and how fast I can make that happen.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thanks. It’s good to know I’m on the right track.

Comment: @Claus Bonnhoff I’ve run this query for a few tables of different sizes, and even for a table with 100 million rows and the same index, it still takes over 3 seconds. Is that a reasonable speed?

Comment: Until MySQL has histogram stats (see MariaDB), the stats will not be very precise.  stats_persistent solves a different problem.

Comment: "how fast I can make that happen" -- But you have only found out how fast _that_ query ran.  It is risky to apply that information to anything else.

Comment: "Is that a reasonable speed" -- If you can estimate the number of blocks touched, you will find the speed to be proportional to that.  Caveat:  If coming from disk, the factor will be several times as large as coming from RAM.  For more detailed discussion, please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, run the timing twice, and indicate whether it is the only secondary index.

Answer (score 4):

Index prefixing rarely helps; often it hurts.

`Using index` says that the index is "covering" and was used.  That is, no need to touch the data.  And, considering the query, nothing better can be done.

So, why did it take so long?  Simple.  It had to walk through ~188M 'rows' in the index.  That may have been a million index blocks.  Each block is 16KB.  How long does your disk take to wade through several GB?  Probably the 30 seconds you experienced is realistic.  Even if all those blocks are cached in the buffer_pool, it takes some amount of time to wade through them.

If there were 1000 distinct values, then the Optimizer would still pick the same query plan ("Using index") and run 100x faster.  The time is proportional to the number of index rows touched.

There are essentially 2 ways to run the query -- Using index versus a table scan.  It picked the "right" one.  No stats, analyzing, etc can help.

If you want to describe the *real* goal, maybe there is a different technique to help -- such as "summary tables".  There are multiple ways to update the stats.  Trigger, a separate Update, a SP, a nightly rollup, etc -- The choice depends on performance, limitations, need for up-to-the-second values, etc.  (Start a new Question if you want to dig deeper.)

Or...  You say there are about 10 distinct values?  Then changing to an `ENUM` would shrink the column to a single byte, and shrink the index by perhaps a factor of two.  If it has to read the index from disk, then it would run twice as fast; if it is entirely cached, then the speedup will be small.

"Throwing hardware at it" is unlikely to help.

- CPU speed -- Before about the year 2000, CPUs were getting faster and faster.  But since then, there has been very little change.
- Number of cores -- MySQL does not make use of more than one core for one query.  (8.0.17(?) has a *very* few cases where it does things in parallel.  I don't think your query is among them.)
- RAM speed -- Also, not getting faster very fast.
- RAM size -- If the index is cached in the buffer pool instead of being read from disk, the speedup is noticeable.  (I suspect you have enough RAM now.)
- Disk speed -- The only big jump disk-read speedup in the last few decades has been from HDD to SSD.  But my Answer was assuming you were using SSDs.